# Import update in Python

Tags: python

So I want to import * from a phyton file. However, these variables I want to import are connected to an API. So they change.

For instance:
at 3:35 is A=5
at 3:36 is A=6

So I want my import to be done every 15 second. How do I write this?

Comment: Don't do `import *` if you want to have the values change. Just `import` the file normally and use the normal `module.attribute` syntax to access the values you want. That way, whenever they're changed inside the module, you'll be able to see the changes.

Comment: How are the variables being updated?  The RIGHT way is to call a function in the imported module that RETURNS the latest values.  Don't rely on globals.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it this way where I just show the schedule to show how the variables can be changed in two files and the schedule represented the change of the API.

In the **file1.py**

```
import schedule
import time

def job(t):
    var1=5
    print(var1)

schedule.every().day.at("3:35").do(job,'It is 3:35')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(15) # wait one minute
```

In the **file2.py**

```
from file1 import var1
import schedule
import time

def job(t):
    var1=6
    print(var1)

schedule.every().day.at("3:36").do(job,'It is 3:36')

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(15) # wait one minute
```

Comment: Are you answering the right question?

Comment: I just use the schedule to show the change of the API.